# Passing data type to repository and using the type in an async task

Tags: c#, api, task, .net-4.5, repository-pattern

I'm certain it is possible to have a repository return objects of various data types.
We have an in-house API that returns student test scores for different types of tests.
My assignment is to get those scores, transform them to a standard model and then import the scores into a
student information system (using another API). Currently I am working on the part of importing the
scores. My plan is to have a processor for each test type that will import, transform and load the scores.
There is a repository that will pull the scores from the API and return them to the processor. Below I have working code that does that
for the Reading scores. But I also have 4 other types of scores, each having a slightly different model, and may
eventually have more.

Below is code that works for the Reading scores, my question is - how can I reuse this repository to
return the differenty score models without writing a Task for each score type?

Here is what I THINK I've figured out so far. The processor should be passing just the type of
score I want, not the specific URL (as my code is currently doing, breaking the reposity pattern), something like:

```
var data = _assessmentAPIRepository.GetScores(Reading);
```

And the interface should be receiving a type, something like...

```
public interface IAssessmentApiRepository<T>
```

But I don't know where to go from there. Could I please get some direction? Pseudo code is great, but
I really need keywords and links to tutorials. I have a Pluralsight account, so if you know of something
there that would help let me know. I don't mind hours of study, but time is importand so I don't want to go
down any rabbit holes.

Working Code:
The processor for the Reading score type:

```
public override IEnumerable Load(ScheduledTask task)
{            
    var dateFromConfig = _assessmentApiRepository.GetBaseCutoffDate();
    string scoresURL = "Reading/scores?includeStrands=False&updatedSince=" + dateFromConfig.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");            
    var data = _assessmentApiRepository.GetScores(scoresURL);
    return data;          
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface IAssessmentApiRepository 
{
    IEnumerable<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>> GetScores(string url);
}
```

The repository:

```
public class AssessmentApiRepository : IAssessmentApiRepository
{
    protected AssessmentsApiConfig _api;
    public AssessmentApiRepository(AssessmentsApiConfig api)
    {
        _api = api;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>> GetScores(string BaseURL)
    {
        var scores = new List<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>>();
        int totalCount = 1;
        int currentCount = 0;
        int page = 1;
        int pageSize = 5000;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            while (totalCount > currentCount)
            {
                string baseAddress = _api.BaseUrl;
                string url = BaseURL + "&page=" + page + "&pageSize=" + pageSize;
                Task<PagedListModel<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>>> task = RunAsync(baseAddress, url);
                foreach (var score in task.Result.Items)
                {
                    scores.Add(score);
                }
                totalCount = task.Result.TotalCount;
                currentCount = currentCount + task.Result.Count;
                page++;
            } 
            return scores;
        }
    }       
    static async Task<PagedListModel<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>>> RunAsync(string baseAddress, string parameter)
    {
        var response = new PagedListModel<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>>();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(parameter);
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<PagedListModel<ReadingCompositeScoreModel<ReadingStrandScoreModel>>>();
            }
            return response;
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Generic and make a repository. Just a snippet using entity framework, you can utilize it in your scenerio

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity,TKey> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
                            string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity GetById(TKey id);
    void Insert(TEntity entityToAdd);
    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
    void Delete(TKey id);
}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class
{
   //Set the variables here
    internal UsersContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

   //Prepare the enviroment here
    public GenericRepository(UsersContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

   /// <summary>
   /// To get all the records
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="filter">Get the filter expression</param>
   /// <param name="orderBy">Get the order by parameters</param>
   /// <param name="includeProperties">Get the include properties</param>
   /// <returns>return the list of records</returns>
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, 
                                                            IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }


        return query.ToList();
    }

   /// <summary>
   /// Get the entity by id
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="id"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
    public TEntity GetById(TKey id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

   /// <summary>
   /// Insert the record
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="entityToAdd">Get the entity to insert</param>
    public void Insert(TEntity entityToAdd)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entityToAdd);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update the record
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityToUpdate">Get the entity to update</param>
    public void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete the entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Get the id to delete</param>
    public void Delete(TKey id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);           
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }

        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the piece my education is missing is the Generics. I'll update my code.

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler answer actually, just focused on the passing of the type. However, your answer is helpful in that it covers the entire project including the passing of Type. So thank you!